Register service and implementation usng AddKeyedScoped
This is my interface
 public interface IService
{
  public Task<string> GetString();
}

THis is my DAL class
 public class SampleDAL : IService
 {
   public async Task<string> GetString()
   { 
     //do something 
   }
 }

This is my BL class
public class SampleBl([FromKeyedServices("SampleBl")]IService service) : IService
{
  public Task<string> GetString()
  {
   var something = service.GetString();
   return something;

  }

}

In my controller I am using the BL
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SampleController([FromKeyedServices("SampleBl")] IService serviceBl) : Controller
{
  [HttpGet("GetSomeString")]
  public async Task<string> GetString()
  {
    var somethingout = serviceBl.GetString();
    return somethingout;
  }
}

In My program.cs I have registered the service and its implementation as
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddKeyedScoped<IService, SampleDal>("SampleDal");
builder.Services.AddKeyedScoped<IService, SampleBl>("SampleBl");

But I am getting error when I run my api. Error is
Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:  Lifetime: Scoped ServiceKey:  KeyedImplementationType: ': A circular dependency was detected for the service of type ''. Please let me know where I am making mistake.

SampleBl gets another SampleBl injected via class SampleBl([FromKeyedServices("SampleBl")]IService service). Did you mean class SampleBl([FromKeyedServices("SampleDal")]IService service)?

yes, now I have removed "[FromKeyedServices("SampleBl")]IService service" from SampleBl

I was able to solve the problem.
I updated my BL class and now I am referrencing "SampleDal" in the class.
public class SampleBl([FromKeyedServices("SampleDal")]IService service) : IService
{
  public Task<string> GetString()
  {
   var something = await service.GetString();
   return something;

  }

}


The following:
public class SampleBl([FromKeyedServices("SampleBl")] IService service) 
    : IService
{
  // ...
}

Means that SampleBl requires service with "SampleBl" key to be resolved, while for this key you register SampleBl itself (AddKeyedScoped<IService, SampleBl>("SampleBl")) which introduces the circular dependency.
Either remove this dependency or change the key to a different one ("SampleDal" for example).
Also without seeing actual code it is hard to tell but in general this seems to be quite an error prone approach and possibly you should use different interfaces on different levels instead of keyed dependencies.
